# How to rid error of null properties in react hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-ref

I'm trying to custom hook to get few data. I want check where is one element in comparison to second element. I want to center it among themselves. It works but I have repeated errors in console.

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading
> 'offsetLeft') at getPosition (usePosition.js:18:1)

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const usePosition = () => {
  const elRef = useRef();
  const elSecondRef = useRef();

  const [fromLeftEl, setFromLeftEl] = useState();
  const [fromTopEl, setFromTopEl] = useState();
  const [widthEl, setWidthEl] = useState();
  const [heightEl, setHeightEl] = useState();
  const [widthElSecond, setWidthElSecond] = useState();

  const [finalX, setFinalX] = useState();
  const [finalY, setFinalY] = useState();
  // This function calculates the position underneath the element and centering it with respect to the other element

  const getPosition = () => {
    const fromLeftEl = elRef.current.offsetLeft;
    setFromLeftEl(fromLeftEl);
    const fromTopEl = elRef.current.offsetTop;
    setFromTopEl(fromTopEl);
    const widthEl = elRef.current.offsetWidth;
    setWidthEl(widthEl);
    const heightEl = elRef.current.offsetHeight;
    setHeightEl(heightEl);
    const widthElSecond = elSecondRef.current.offsetWidth;
    setWidthElSecond(widthElSecond);
    const middleEl = widthEl / 2;
    const middleElSecond = widthElSecond / 2;
    const finalX = fromLeftEl + middleEl - middleElSecond;
    setFinalX(finalX);
    const finalY = fromTopEl + heightEl;
    setFinalY(finalY);
  };
  // Get the position of the first element
  useEffect(() => {
    getPosition();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", getPosition);
    window.addEventListener("click", getPosition);
    window.addEventListener("scroll", getPosition);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", getPosition);
  }, []);

  return {
    elRef,
    elSecondRef,
    fromLeftEl,
    fromTopEl,
    widthEl,
    heightEl,
    finalY,
    finalX,
    widthElSecond,
  };
};
export default usePosition;
```

component that uses usePosition:

```
import classNames from "classnames";
import { useState } from "react";
import useSticky from "./useSticky";
import usePosition from "./usePosition";

import "../style/sass/Nav.sass";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Nav = (props) => {
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);
  const { sticky, stickyRef } = useSticky();
  const { elRef, elSecondRef, finalY, finalX } = usePosition();

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setActive(!isActive);
  };

  return (
    <div
      ref={stickyRef}
      className={classNames("nav", { sticky })}
      style={{
        display: props.display,
        height: sticky ? `${stickyRef.current?.clientHeight}px` : "10vh",
        width: props.width,
        gridTemplateColumns: props.navGridCol,
        gridTemplateRows: props.navGridRow,
        height: props.height,
        position: props.position,
        left: props.left,
        animation: props.animationMenu,
      }}
    >
      <div
        className="nav__logo"
        style={{
          gridArea: props.gArea1,
          height: props.heightHomeBtn,
          width: props.btnWidth,
          animation: props.animationHome,
          display: props.homeDisplay,
        }}
      >
        <NavLink className="link__logo" to="/">
          <i
            class="icon-home"
            style={{
              width: props.btnWidth,
              fontSize: props.fweight,
            }}
          ></i>
        </NavLink>
      </div>
      <NavLink
        className="link__about"
        to="/about"
        exact="true"
        style={{ gridArea: props.gArea2 }}
      >
        <button
          className="nav__aboutBtn"
          style={{
            height: props.btnHeight,
            width: props.btnWidth,
            animation: props.animationAbout,
            display: props.aboutDisplay,
          }}
        >
          <p>o firmie</p>
        </button>
      </NavLink>
      <button
        onClick={handleToggle}
        className={!isActive ? "offerDD__btn" : "offerDD__btn_active"}
        style={{
          gridArea: props.gArea3,
          height: props.btnHeight,
          width: props.btnWidth,
          animation: props.animationOffer,
          display: props.offerDisplay,
        }}
        ref={elRef}
      >
        <i class="icon-down-open"></i>
        <p>oferta</p>
      </button>
      <div
        className={
          !isActive ? "offerDD__dropdown_disabled" : "offerDD__dropdown"
        }
        ref={elSecondRef}
        style={{ top: `${finalY}px`, left: `${finalX}px` }}
      >
        <NavLink className="link__air" to="/air-conditioning">
          <div
            className="air__p"
            style={{ height: props.btnHeight, width: props.btnWidth }}
          >
            <p>klimatyzacje</p>
          </div>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink className="link__vent" to="/ventilation">
          <div
            className="vent__p"
            style={{ height: props.btnHeight, width: props.btnWidth }}
          >
            <p>wentylacje</p>
          </div>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink className="link__heat" to="/heat-pump">
          <div
            className="heat__p"
            style={{ height: props.btnHeight, width: props.btnWidth }}
          >
            <p>pompy ciepła</p>
          </div>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink className="link__recu" to="/recuperation">
          <div
            className="recu__p"
            style={{ height: props.btnHeight, width: props.btnWidth }}
          >
            <p>rekuperacja</p>
          </div>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink className="link__fire-protection" to="/fire-protection">
          <div
            className="fire__p"
            style={{ height: props.btnHeight, width: props.btnWidth }}
          >
            <p>ppoż</p>
          </div>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink className="link__shop" to="/shop">
          <div
            className="shop__p"
            style={{ height: props.btnHeight, width: props.btnWidth }}
          >
            <p>sklep</p>
          </div>
        </NavLink>
      </div>
      <NavLink
        className="link__blog"
        to="/blog"
        style={{ gridArea: props.gArea4 }}
      >
        <button
          className="nav__blogBtn"
          style={{
            height: props.btnHeight,
            width: props.btnWidth,
            animation: props.animationBlog,
            display: props.blogDisplay,
          }}
        >
          <p>blog</p>
        </button>
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink
        className="link__contact"
        to="/contact"
        style={{ gridArea: props.gArea5 }}
      >
        <button
          className="nav__contactBtn"
          style={{
            height: props.btnHeight,
            width: props.btnWidth,
            animation: props.animationContact,
            display: props.contactDisplay,
          }}
        >
          <p>kontakt</p>
        </button>
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink
        className="link__login"
        to="/login"
        style={{ gridArea: props.gArea6 }}
      >
        <button
          className="nav__loginBtn"
          style={{
            height: props.btnHeight,
            width: props.btnWidth,
            animation: props.animationLogin,
            display: props.loginDisplay,
          }}
        >
          <p>zaloguj</p>
        </button>
      </NavLink>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

I want know how to code this issue correctly without error in console and working hook.

I know that this error is due to the fact that it is impossible to read something that is not there and therefore it is null but how to write this code to make it correct?

Comment: short answer, basically you are getting null instead of your expected element. try using `useLayoutEffect` to make sure elements are ready in the dom before you manipulate them

Comment: The ref isn't set or attached to a DOMNode yet. Can you [edit] to share how this `usePosition` hook is used? See [mcve].

Comment: @ Semi-Friends I tried use useLayoutEffect but is the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any overt issue with the way the `elRef` is used in the consuming component. `elRef` is attached to a DOM element, e.g. `button`, and there is no conditional rendering so `button` is rendered to the DOM during the initial render.

```
const Nav = (props) => {
  ...
  const { elRef, elSecondRef, finalY, finalX } = usePosition();

  ...

  return (
    <div
      ...
    >
      ...
      <button
        onClick={handleToggle}
        className={!isActive ? "offerDD__btn" : "offerDD__btn_active"}
        style={{
          gridArea: props.gArea3,
          height: props.btnHeight,
          width: props.btnWidth,
          animation: props.animationOffer,
          display: props.offerDisplay,
        }}
        ref={elRef}
      >
        <i class="icon-down-open"></i>
        <p>oferta</p>
      </button>
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

I do however see potential issue in the `usePosition` hook. The hook doesn't clean up all the effects it creates. In the case of accessing into potentially null or undefined references it is advised to use a null-check/guard-clause or the Optional Chaining operator prior to accessing properties. In this case an `if` block to check if the refs have a truthy current value is sufficient.

```
const usePosition = () => {
  const elRef = useRef();
  const elSecondRef = useRef();

  const [fromLeftEl, setFromLeftEl] = useState();
  const [fromTopEl, setFromTopEl] = useState();
  const [widthEl, setWidthEl] = useState();
  const [heightEl, setHeightEl] = useState();
  const [widthElSecond, setWidthElSecond] = useState();

  const [finalX, setFinalX] = useState();
  const [finalY, setFinalY] = useState();

  // This function calculates the position underneath the element and centering it with respect to the other element
  const getPosition = () => {
    // Only access ref properties if there is a current value
    if (elRef.current && elSecondRef.current) {
      const fromLeftEl = elRef.current.offsetLeft;
      setFromLeftEl(fromLeftEl);
      const fromTopEl = elRef.current.offsetTop;
      setFromTopEl(fromTopEl);
      const widthEl = elRef.current.offsetWidth;
      setWidthEl(widthEl);
      const heightEl = elRef.current.offsetHeight;
      setHeightEl(heightEl);

      const widthElSecond = elSecondRef.current.offsetWidth;
      setWidthElSecond(widthElSecond);

      const middleEl = widthEl / 2;
      const middleElSecond = widthElSecond / 2;
      const finalX = fromLeftEl + middleEl - middleElSecond;
      setFinalX(finalX);

      const finalY = fromTopEl + heightEl;
      setFinalY(finalY);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", getPosition, { passive: true });
    window.addEventListener("click", getPosition);
    window.addEventListener("scroll", getPosition, { passive: true });

    // Call once on initial component render
    getPosition();

    // Return cleanup function to remove all listener callbacks!
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", getPosition, { passive: true });
      window.removeEventListener("click", getPosition);
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", getPosition, { passive: true });
    };
  }, []);

  return {
    elRef,
    elSecondRef,
    fromLeftEl,
    fromTopEl,
    widthEl,
    heightEl,
    finalY,
    finalX,
    widthElSecond,
  };
};

export default usePosition;
```